# Start a new page in two-column mode without \clearpage

Tags: page-breaking, two-column, afterpage, clearpage

I have the challenge of needing to start a *clean page* in a *two-column* (Xe)LaTeX document, yet *without the fush* semantics of `\clearpage`.

Consider the following example, which is the closest I got to achieving the desired output:

```
\afterpage
{
    \clearpage
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,x=\paperwidth,y=\paperheight]%
        ...
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \clearpage
}
```

This waits until the current page has ended, and then fills in a `tikzpicture`, such that I can draw on an empty following page. After this drawing, the regular document resumes - just like pasting a picture page into the regular document.

However, the following problems exist:

- Due to the `\clearpage`, the above code forces all prior floats to be flushed. This is actually undesired since I have plenty of floats and I don't want the tikzpicture to interfere with the placement. I would like to **avoid the flushing**.
- If I replace  `\clearpage` with `\newpage`, I can avoid the flushing but this approach is unsuitable for a two-column document, since there `\newpage` changes its meaning to starting a new column.
- If I replace  `\clearpage` with `\newpage~\newpage` I must always make sure to only trigger it after even columns.
- If I *remove* the first `\clearpage`, the `tikzpicture` actually does start on a new page as desired; however, the subsequent document content is placed below the `tikzpicture`.

I assume that two different solution approaches may be possible but I did not manage to succeed with either one:

- Find a two-column `\clearpage` without flush
- Use `\afterpage{\tikz{...}\magic\newpage~\newpage}` where `\magic` assures that no other content appears on the page.

Any suggestions or thoughts would be most appreciated.

Comment: the full documentation of `\afterpage` in a two column document is **"This implementation does not work in two column mode"** (page 1 of `texdoc afterpage`}

Comment: @DavidCarlisle You think people read footnotes?

Answer (score 1):

The `\null` is because you can't have two `\newpage`s (or `\newcolumn`s) in a row.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\let\newcolumn=\newpage
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\newpage}{\if@firstcolumn\newcolumn\null\fi \newcolumn}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\newpage
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\nell` -> `\null`?